# Delaying/Disabling Form Submit using Adobe DTM

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I have been trying to delay a form submission using Adobe's DTM. The page only has one form on it. I set-up a page load rule to test to see if I can even stop the submission of the form. What I did is create a rule that fires on DOM ready but I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

I have the following in third party scripts to test (execute globally is checked & non-sequential JS).

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

But as I mentioned I get the above error. Not sure why? Everything I've read talks about the form not being rendered yet etc. Any ideas how I can accomplish this in DTM? My plan is to perform so JS and then submit the form but I can't even get this working?

Comment: It sounds like your js is running before the form exists. To test just add console.log(document.querySelector('form')); above the code you shared. If thats the case, you should change your code to fire on page bottom and see if that helps.

Comment: What about the reverse -  submit the form only after an event or action is completed?